# Hide top panel when inspecting elements

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When we use Chrome developer tools for inspecting elements, top panel will show up where we can choose  which device chrome will emulate, what network throttle setting, there will also be a ruler top and sideways... is there an option to temporarely remove all that?

I work on laptop and my screen isn't as big as I would like to, and when inspecting elements, it becomes even smaller, and at lot of times I don't need those options.

There is only a button for hiding media queries and it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the result of mobile emulation mode. There is a small button on the left side of the menu bar. It looks like a phone. You can click on  and switch off the emulation mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the main Dev tool window, click on the kebob menu and then Toggle device Toolbar.